After spring upgradation to 1.5.9.RELEASE, my application is failing to run with some error as "Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]"
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            name 'nexus'
            url "http://nexus.engati.ops:8081/repository/coviam-artifactory/"
            credentials {
                username repoUser
                password repoPassword
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("com.nethum.common:custom-plugin-service:1.0.0.2")
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.1"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.2.0"
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '3.1.1'
    id 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless' version '4.5.1'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'
apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'nexus'
        url "http://nexus.engati.ops:8081/repository/coviam-artifactory/"
        credentials {
            username repoUser
            password repoPassword
        }
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}

group 'com.engati'
if (project.hasProperty('appVersion')) {
    version = "${appVersion}"
} else {
    version = "${version}-BRANCH-${grgit.branch.current().name}-SNAPSHOT"
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.3')
    compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '1.3.2.RELEASE')
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE')
    compile('org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.3.5')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.4.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.3.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.12')
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}")
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7')
    compile('net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.7')
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.1.7')
    compile('net.rakugakibox.springbootext:spring-boot-ext-logback-access:1.6')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0')
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.58')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.0.32')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-tx')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1')
    compile("commons-net:commons-net:${commons_net_version}")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1')
    compile('redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.4.0')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.4.0')
    compile('io.prometheus:simpleclient_spring_boot:0.0.18')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.0.0.RELEASE')
    compile('com.nethum.common:datetime-service:1.0.0.2')
    compile('com.nethum.common:nickfury-api-service:1.0.0.2')
    compile('com.nethum.common:data-processor-api-service:1.0.0.3')
    compile('com.nethum.common:natasha-api-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:0.5.0')
    compile('net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-jdbc-template:0.5.0')
    compile('com.nethum.common:error-handling-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('com.nethum.common:error-handling-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.17')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17')
    compile('com.nethum.common:tag-service-sdk:1.0.0.2')
    compile('com.peoplehum.common:attachment-service:1.0.0.3')
    compile('com.peoplehum.common:platform-service-sdk:1.0.0.2')
    compile('com.peoplehum.common:user-service-sdk:1.0.0.2')
    compile('com.peoplehum.common:http-service-sdk:1.0.0.3')
    compile('com.nethum.common:custom-annotation-service:1.0.0.3')
    compile('com.peoplehum.common:redis-sdk:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okhttp_version}")
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: "${okhttp_version}"
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'retrofit', version: "${retrofit_version}"
    compile group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-jackson', version: "${retrofit_version}"
    compile(group: 'com.engati', name: 'livechat-models-sdk', version: "${livechat_models_sdk_version}")
    compile(group: 'com.engati', name: 'onboarding-model-sdk', version: "${onboarding_model_sdk_version}")
    compile(group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: "${json_simple_version}")
    compile("com.peoplehum.common:payment-service-sdk:${payment_service_sdk_version}")
    compile(group: 'com.engati.common', name: 'bundle-model-sdk', version: "${bundle_model_sdk_version}")
    compile(group: 'com.nethum.common', name: 'notification-service-sdk', version: "${notification_service_version}")
    compile("com.engati:audit-service:${audit_service_version}")
    compile('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.16') {
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
        exclude group: "com.healthmarketscience.jackcess", module: "jackcess-encrypt"
        exclude group: "com.healthmarketscience.jackcess", module: "jackcess"
        exclude group: "org.gagravarr", module: "vorbis-java-tika"
        exclude group: "org.tallison", module: "jmatio"
        exclude group: "org.tukaani", module: "xz"
        exclude group: "org.bouncycastle", module: "bcmail-jdk15on"
        exclude group: "org.bouncycastle", module: "bcprov-jdk15on"
        exclude group: "org.apache.pdfbox", module: "pdfbox-tools"
        exclude group: "org.apache.pdfbox", module: "jempbox"
        exclude group: "org.apache.poi", module: "poi-scratchpad"
        exclude group: "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup", module: "tagsoup"
        exclude group: "org.ow2.asm", module: "asm"
        exclude group: "com.googlecode.mp4parser:", module: "isoparser"
        exclude group: "de.l3s.boilerpipe", module: "boilerpipe"
        exclude group: "com.rometools", module: "rome"
        exclude group: "org.gagravarr", module: "vorbis-java-core"
        exclude group: "com.pff", module: "java-libpst"
        exclude group: "com.github.junrar", module: "junrar"
        exclude group: "org.apache.cxf", module: "cxf-rt-rs-client"
        exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-exec"
        exclude group: "commons-io", module: "commons-io"
        exclude group: "com.googlecode.json-simple", module: "json-simple"
        exclude group: "com.tdunning", module: "json"
        exclude group: "com.google.code.gson", module: "gson"
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-api"
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jul-to-slf4j"
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jcl-over-slf4j"
        exclude group: "edu.ucar", module: "netcdf4"
        exclude group: "edu.ucar", module: "grib"
        exclude group: "edu.ucar", module: "cdm"
        exclude group: "edu.ucar", module: "httpservices"
        exclude group: "org.apache.sis.core", module: "sis-utility"
        exclude group: "org.apache.sis.storage", module: "sis-netcdf"
        exclude group: "org.apache.sis.core", module: "sis-metadata"
        exclude group: "org.opengis", module: "geoapi"
        exclude group: "edu.usc.ir", module: "sentiment-analysis-parser"
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-core"
    }
    compile(group: 'com.engati', name: 'redis-sync-service-model', version: "${redis_sync_model_version}")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.196')
    testCompile("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:${retrofit_version}")
    compile(group: "com.engati.platform", name: "bot-external-api-event-model", version: "${bot_external_api_version}") {
        exclude(module: "bot-external-api-constant")
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.0.0'
    compile(group: 'com.engati.common', name: 'broadcast-service-sdk', version: "${broadcast_service_sdk_version}") {
        exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"
        exclude group: "org.projectlombok"
        exclude group: "org.apache.commons"
        exclude group: "com.googlecode.json-simple"
        exclude group: "com.engati", module: "interaction-commons"
        exclude group: "com.engati.common", module: "user-identification-sdk"
        exclude group: "com.engati.platform", module: "attribute-model"
    }
}
}

I am getting the following error, and below is the thread dump
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

I checked these
For Java Servlet API Version:
Check Web Container Documentation: If you're deploying your application to a specific web container (like Apache Tomcat, Jetty, or any other), you can refer to its documentation to find out which version of the Servlet API it supports.
Check Servlet API JAR: If you have access to the libraries used in your project, you can locate the Servlet API JAR file and inspect its version. The Servlet API JAR file typically has a name like servlet-api-x.x.jar or javax.servlet-api-x.x.jar. The version can often be found in the file name or in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file inside the JAR.

Using gradle 4.4.1 and java 1.8

Can you share the complete log? Some earlier output should provide some clues as to why the Tomcat components were unable to start. You should also review all of your dependencies. Many of them have versions declared when they're already managed by Spring Boot. Using Spring Boot's default versions should reduce the possibility of version incompatibilities.

It does not allow me to print the dump due to character limit

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found the solution, it was a version mismatch for some dependencies and it was also because of this dependency
compile('net.rakugakibox.springbootext:spring-boot-ext-logback-access:1.6')

Removing which resolved the error
